# Rails 3 - How to sort an array by number of duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, sorting

Sorry for the noob question (i guess...).

Say I have an array of post_commenters with user_id & comment_id 
E.g.: 
1 - 27
2 - 31
1 - 54
3 - 87
1 - 12
2 - 54

If I wanted to rank the users by their number of comments, I'd have to count the number of times they have commented, and then .uniq it.

**How can I do that ?**

I know how to uniq it:

```
unique_user_list = array.uniq {|s| s.user_id}
```

I know how to count the duplicates inside the array:

```
array.count { |u| u.name == unique_user_list.name  } # in a loop of user
```

But i'm at a loss to mix and sort by number of duplicates...

Thank you!

**EDIT**

Ok, thanks to floatless, i'm now at something more tangible - with a real example from the foursquare api, using quimby gem:

```
- current_user.all_checkins.group_by(&:venue["id"]).first(50).each do |c|
  = c.venue.id
```

Only problem, it doesn't .... group. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use a `GROUP BY` clause inside your SQL query to do that and then just `COUNT` grouped comments.

Comment: My example was a dummy example - i'm getting an array from an api, don't think the group_by works here...